# How to call the same function in two different ways?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to combine a function which will display alert *(ofcourse I have a lot of code In this function but for this case It will be alert)* after:

1. `Click` on element with class `.number`
2. `Change` `select[name=receive]`

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).on(("click",".number"),("change","select[name=receive]"),function(){
    alert('test');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function doMyWork() {
    console.lot( 'TEST' );
}
$('.number').on('click', doMyWork);
$('select[name=receive]').on('change', doMyWork);
```

Or, if your elements are inserted after DOM ready:
*You do not have to use this form if the target elements exist at `DOM ready`*

```
function doMyWork() {
    console.lot( 'TEST' );
}
$(document).on('click', '.number', doMyWork)
.on('change', 'select[name=receive]', doMyWork);
```

Comment: This is the best solution for me. Works perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Cool. Glad you found this helpful. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click change","select[name=receive], .number", function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Or

```
var fn = function () {
   alert('test');
}

$(document).on("click", ".number", fn);
$(document).on("change", "select[name=receive]", fn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot separate events and selectors in a single `.on()` call. You have two options here. You can use them together....

```
$(document).on("click change", ".number, select[name=receive]"),function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

...however this means that *.number* will listen to both click and change, possible resulting in the function running 2 times.

You need to move the function outside and reuse it for every handler

```
var al = function(){
    alert('test');
};

$('.number').on('click', al);
$('select[name=receive]').on('change', al);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click change",".number, select[name=receive]", function(){
    alert('test');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you learned that syntax, but that is not how on() works.

Use a named function and share it.

```
(function(){

   var shared = function(){
       console.log(this); 
   }

   $(document)
       .on("click",".number", shared)
       .on("change","select[name=receive]", shared);  

}());
```